# Golang JSON Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: json, go, serialization

I have a struct as follows:

```
type Node struct {
    Name     string
    Children []*Node
    Values   []string
}
```

I also have a set of json files describing my trees such as:

```
{
  "something": {
    "someblah": [
      "fluf",
      "glah"
    ],
    "someother": {
      "someotter": [
        "blib",
        "fnar"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I deserialize these files into the structs?

All the examples I found seem to require a different structure with named key/value pairs.

For this, the structure is key:

- the key is the struct name
- the map contents are children
- the lists contents are values

I cannot understand how to map this logic into the golang json serializer.

Comment: why not unmarshal into `map[string]interface{}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach is to decode to map[string]interface{} and convert that to the desired structure:

```
var m map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
node := convert(m, "")

...

func convert(name string, m map[string]interface{}) *Node {
    n := Node{Name: name}
    for k, v := range m {
        switch v := v.(type) {
        case []interface{}:
            nn := Node{Name: k}
            for _, e := range v {
                s, ok := e.(string)
                if !ok {
                    panic(fmt.Sprintf("expected string, got %T", e))
                }
                nn.Values = append(nn.Values, s)
            }
            n.Children = append(n.Children, &nn)
        case map[string]interface{}:
            n.Children = append(n.Children, convert(k, v))
        default:
            panic("unexpected type")
        }
    }
    return &n
}
```

The `convert` function panics when it encounters a value of an unexpected type. Depending on the requirements of your application, you may want to ignore these values or return an error.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-mnrYwVumt9).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the correct solution. However, there seems to be a bug in the example: In the values case, there is no node created and the values are attached to the parent. In the example, each node has either children or values.

Comment: @Wilbert See updated answer.  It would have been helpful if the question showed an example of the expected result.